# How to call a php function on button click with one param

Tags: php, html

I want to call a php function with one param, id of a button, when I press that button.
This is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
include ("sterge2.html");
<button onclick="writeMsg(this.id)">Click me</button>

function writeMsg($id) {
     echo $id."Hello world!";
     //add that id in a database...
}


?>

</body>

</html>
```

But it does nothing...

Comment: You cannot combine javascript and PHP, PHP is a server side language that gets processed before your HTML page is generated. You should use AJAX instead

Comment: *add that id in a database...* indicates that you're looking for AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can not combine javascript and php. instead of it use ajax.
try below ajax code..

```
 <button class="btnsubmit" id="submit" data-id="5" >Click me</button>

    $(".btnsubmit").click(function() {

                   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

                       $.ajax({

                       url : URL+'writeMsg',
                       type : 'POST',
                       data : {'id': id},
                       success : function(data)
                       {

                       }
                   });
                });
```

and in writeMsg function perform database opertaion.
i hope this code will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        include ("sterge2.html");
        echo '<button onclick="writeMsg(this.id)">Click me</button>';
        ?>

        <script>
        function writeMsg(id) {
             alert(id + "Hello world!");
             // Use AJAX to call PHP file and save id into DB
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How should I use ajax? I never used it before....Do I have to instal or include something ?

Comment: Please check Rubby Smith answer. Need to add jQuery library in your page head.

Answer (score 0):

With `onclick`-event you can call a javascript function. Not php.
Just try this.

```
<!--html -->
<button  onclick="writeMsg(<?php echo $id_val ?>)">Click me</button>
<!--html -->
```

Function will be included in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript>">
var id;
function writeMsg(id) {
      alert(id."Hello world!");//give you result

}
</script>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question